# Django Rest Framework - adding permissions for views based on groups?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

**TLDR: How do you permit specific Groups access to views using Django Rest Framework?**

---

I'm in the process of building a web service with the Django Rest Framework. Only a (proper) subset of the views are intended to be available to customers.

So far, I've:

1. set the default permission to `rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser`
2. created a permission called `is_customer` (using the Django admin website)
3. created a Group called `customers` and added all relevant users to this group (using the admin website)
4. added the `is_customer` permission to `customers` (again using the admin website)

All of my views are function-based. To provide the appropriate permission to the `customers` group, I've tried

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_required(["is_customer"])
def my_func(request):
  # calculations
  return Response(...)
```

---

**EDIT: also tried the below method**

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class IsCustomer(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_customer:
            return True
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.is_customer:
            return True
        return False

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_required([IsCustomer])
def my_func(request):
  # calculations
  return Response(...)
```

and

```py
from rest_framework.decorators permission_classes, api_view

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes(["is_customer"])
def my_func(request):
  # calculations
  return Response(...)
```

and neither seems to be working. What is the proper way to go about this? Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsCustomer` class was not set up properly. This is what the class should look like:

```py
class IsCustomer(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if 'auth.is_customer' in request.user.get_all_permissions():
            return True
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if 'auth.is_customer' in request.user.get_all_permissions():
            return True
        return False
```

From there, using the `@permission_classes([IsCustomer])` works as intended. Therefore the final form of the view is:

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsCustomer])
def testing_post(request):
    try:
        someData = someCalculations()
        return Response(data=someData, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e.args[0], status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

The last block should work if you reference the class directly:

```
from rest_framework.decorators permission_classes, api_view

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsCustomer])
def my_func(request):
    # calculations
    return Response(...)
```

You can view the documentation with a similar example here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: I guess the problem was with the Permission class definition. `request.user` does not have an `is_customer` attribute. You have to return its permissions and then see if the appropriate one is in the set. See the answer for details if you're interested!